# Users are not figuring out that they can use breadcrumb to navigate to go to the previous page

Tags: usability, ux-designer, usability-study, back-button, breadcrumbs

[[image: This is the screenshot of the breadcrumb navigation where users face issue, 1]

This is the screenshot of the breadcrumb navigation where users face issue,

Comment: Can you include more info? How do you know users are not using it, what kind of tests did you run, what other options are they using instead of teh breadcrumb?

Comment: It seems to be a web application. The most used button is the browser’s back button. Does it work in that application? I second Devin’s question: What was the task given to the user that required navigating up in the hierarchy?

Comment: @Devin This issues was noticed during a setup call with a user. It was a recurring issue where users stumble upon navigating back to the page "production team" , The flow that they are using is side_navbar > teams > production teams

Comment: @Andy It is a web application, and the back button works too, the task was to navigate back to "production teams".

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a signifier such as a colour, that makes the text look more like a link you can click on?

I've even seen some designers use pills/buttons for each page title, to make it more apparent that these are interactive elements.